# Openpyxl: "permission denied" but Excel sheet not open

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a piece of code I've been using successfully for quite a while. There is a piece of it that loops through a small list of employees and writes each of their top 20 products to an Excel sheet. Now it is often (but not always) throwing an error: (see below for full traceback)

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

I.e., the error you'd get if you accidentally had the spreadsheet open when running the code. This is not the case now. Here's the relevant code:

```
for e in employee_list:
    df4 = e
    df4 = pd.DataFrame()
    df4 = df4.append(df3.loc[df3['Employee'] == e], sort = False)

    book = load_workbook(filename)
    sheet = e + '_qtr'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    df4.to_excel (writer, sheet)
    writer.save()
```

A thought I had was perhaps the code is running faster now? I made some minor changes to the code meant to streamline it before this error started happening. Could it be that OpenPyXL is still working on saving when the loop comes back around?

Any help is appreciated!

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scorecard_3.py", line 390, in <module>
    sc_attrib(f, p)
  File "scorecard_3.py", line 367, in sc_attrib
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\arbit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1018, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "C:\Users\arbit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 367, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\arbit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 282, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\arbit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\arbit\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Scorecard 3.0.xlsx'
```

Comment: Include the full traceback but I suspect you don't have permissions to load the workbook.

Comment: It will open the spreadsheet and post some of the data, giving the error at some point during the loop. Not the first loop, nor consistently any given loop.

Comment: As I said, the problem arises when you try and save the file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Microsoft Onedrive was trying to upload the file to the cloud while I was working with it. I've changed those settings and now it works fine!